# Jquery custom validation - last form-field not validating

Tags: jquery, validation, error-handling

I have a problem with validating my form. **When I leave all fields/textarea's blank, excluded from the last one, my form does nothing on the submit action... This also happens when I only have one textfield/textarea to validate.** I have no idea how this is possible because when I log out my errors it shows all the errors that should be displayed, but it isn't added on the page itself.
Here is my code:

1) JQuery code (this is triggered in the `$(document).ready(function(ev){ initialiseValidation() });`

```
function initialiseValidation()
{

   $('form').each(function()
   {
        var validators = [];
        var form = $(this);
        var textfields = form.find("input[type]").not("input[type=submit]");
        var textareas = form.find("textarea");
        var formfields = $.merge(textfields, textareas);

        formfields.each(function()
        {
            var inputfield = $(this);
            var field = inputfield.find('[name=' + inputfield.attr('name') + ']');
            var type = inputfield.attr('type') == undefined ? 'textarea' : inputfield.attr('type');
            var label = inputfield.attr("name");


            function hide_feedback(message)
            {
                $('.errormessages').remove();
            }

            function show_feedback(message){
                    // Insert own error message
                $(".formulier").before($('<ul/>').addClass('errormessages contact').append($('<li/>').text(message)));
            }


            if(inputfield.length)
            {
                if (inputfield.is("input") || inputfield.is("textarea"))
                {

                    function validator()
                    {
                        var error = undefined;


                             if (!inputfield.val())
                                error = getMessageForLabel(label);

                            else if (label == 'email' && ! inputfield.val().match(/.+@.+\..+/))
                                error = "Gelieve een geldig e-mail adres in te geven.";

                            else if(label == "username" && checkUsername())
                                 error = "Username bestaat niet.";

                                hide_feedback();


                            if (error)
                            {
                                    show_feedback(error);
                                  throw new ValidationError(label, error, function () {
                                                                    field.focus();
                                                                    return false;
                                  });
                            }

                        }


                    // Validator for field.onchange
                    function quick_validate(event)
                    {
                        // Ignore tab-key
                        //log(event.keyCode);
                        if (event.keyCode != 9)
                        {

                            try {

                                validator();
                            }
                            catch(validation_error) {

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    inputfield.change(quick_validate).keyup(quick_validate).blur(quick_validate);

                    // Validator for form.submit
                    validators.push(validator);
                }
            }
        });


          $(this).submit(function(ev)
          {
                var errors = [];

                // Call all validators
                for (var v in validators)
                {
                    try {

                        validators[v]();
                    }
                    catch(validation_error)
                    {

                        errors.push(validation_error);
                    }
                }

               if (errors.length)
               {

                   $('.errormessages').empty();

                       for(var i in errors)
                       {
                           var msg = errors[i]['error_msg'];
                           $(".errormessages").append($('<li/>').text(msg));
                       }

                   return false;

               }


          });

    });

}


function ValidationError(label, error_msg, ok_callback)
{
    this.label = label;
    this.error_msg = error_msg;
    this.ok_callback = ok_callback;
}
```

2) HTML code (not the best, all the classes are used to make the styling better...)

```
<form action="index.php?page=contact&amp;action=confirm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="contactform">

            {if !empty($errorArr)}
                <ul class="errormessages contact">
                    {foreach $errorArr as $error}
                    <li>{$error}</li>
                    {/foreach}
                </ul>
            {/if}


            <div class="formulier">

                <div class="formblock">
                    <div class="label">
                        <label for="naam">Voornaam:</label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" name="naam" id="naam" autocomplete="true" value="{if isset($smarty.post.naam)}{$smarty.post.naam}{/if}"/>
                </div>
                </br>
                <div class="formblock">
                    <div class="label">
                        <label for="familienaam">Naam:</label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" name="familienaam" id="familienaam" autocomplete="true" value="{if isset($smarty.post.familienaam)}{$smarty.post.familienaam}{/if}"/>

                </div>
                </br>
                <div class="formblock">
                    <div class="label">
                        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="true" value="{if isset($smarty.post.email)}{$smarty.post.email}{/if}"/>

                </div>
                </br>
                <div class="formblock">
                    <div class="label">
                        <label for="bericht">Bericht:</label>
                    </div>
                    <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="bericht" id="bericht">{if isset($smarty.post.bericht)}{$smarty.post.bericht}{/if}</textarea>

                </div>
                </br>
                <div class="formblock">

                    <input type="submit" value="stuur bericht" name="validateMail" id="validateMail"/>

                </div>

            </div>


        </form>
```

I searched a lot on the web but I can't find a solution for this problem, so if you have any tips/solutions it would be highly appreciated!

Comment: When you call `hide_feedback();`. Do you mean to remove the element completely?

Comment: Well yes, before you submit it just validates each input-field separately but when you submit it checks all fields at once. so when you press tab/click out of an inputfield, it removes the errormessages **unordered** list, as when you press submit it clears out the errormessages and replaces them with the needed errors. Because when I don't delete the ul-tag (errormessages) you can see layout changes